# How to add another column in RGA?

Tags: r, analytics

I need to calculate the Conversion rate for TOP-10 countries. I have the number of sessions and number of conversions.

I need to add another value to the table which can be calculated using this formula: `cv_rate = number_of_conversions*100/sessions`

Output I have now:
`Country - sessions - number_of_conversions`

And I need

```
Country - sessions  - number_of_conversions  -     cv_rate=number_of_conversions*100/sessions
```

How do I add this row to my table?

```
ga.data= ga$getData("ga:xxx", batch = TRUE, walk = TRUE, "2015-06-29", "2015-07-05",
                     metrics = "ga:sessions, ga:goal20Completions",
                     dimensions = "ga:country",
                     sort = "-ga:sessions", filters = "",
                     segment = "sessions::condition::ga:deviceCategory==desktop;ga:operatingSystem!=Macintosh;ga:userType==New%20Visitor",
                     max=10)

## Then we aggregate all data by Country
ga2.data= aggregate(cbind(sessions, goal20Completions) ~ country, ga.data, FUN="sum")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what I needed

```
cv_rate =  ga2.data["goal20Completions"] / ga2.data$sessions*100
##And Finally We have to merge all data together: Country + sessions + number of conversions + Conversion rate
r3.data = cbind(ga2.data, cv_rate)
```